# Entity Framework Core - Can I query lists/objects in child property directly avoiding multiple repeating Include/ThenInclude?

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

In our backend we have a LINQ query to retrieve customer information for a given purchase that is something like:

```
var serviceRequest = await _dbContext.Purchases
    .Include(p => p.Customer)
      .ThenInclude(c => c.Addresses)
    .Include(p => p.Customer)
      .ThenInclude(c => c.EmailAddresses)
    .Include(p => p.Customer)
      .ThenInclude(c => c.PhoneNumbers)
```

And we want to refactor it and avoid repeating

```
Include(p=>p.blablabla)
```

whenever we want to add something more to retrieve. So our objective was modifying this original LINQ to

```
var serviceRequest = await _dbContext.Purchases
    .Include(p => p.Customer.Addresses)
    .Include(p => p.Customer.EmailAddresses)
    .Include(p => p.Customer.PhoneNumbers)
```

Using a SQL profiler we've observed that the queries generated by EFCore are the same and the apparent result objects are similar, so our question is: is there a way, best practice or reason to use multiple Include and ThenInclude even when the second option is in our opinion more clear and readable? Are there side effects with eager loading (which we are using by default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have did everything right. ThenLoad are useful if they follow after one-to-many `Include`.

About side effects: everything should work or EF Core team broke this ;)
It is documented, for example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-3.1 but as string property path, which should be the same.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the reference! I don't know why I did not take a look to msft include docs before. With the profiler and the EF output we saw similar queries but we didn't know for sure if that had side effects in EF Core. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlosDraperGiggs, you should know that `Include` is just declarative extension - which related entities to load. If entities are loaded - declaration was successful.